# Method that returns block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I wrote a method that can be used with a dot notation, using block tricks

`- (RaginiDBQuery *(^)(id object))where;`

This method can be called using a dot notation since basically it doesn't receive any parameters, (it does, but by using the block returned)

So I can call it like so:

`query.where(object)`

What I need it instead getting an `id object` I want to receive something like in this method:

`- (NSEnumerator *)where:(BOOL (^)(id object))predicate;`

this method can be called like so:

`[object where:^(id a){return [a intValue]%2 == 1}];`

What I want is to combine both, calling my method `where` using the dot notation, but sending it a predicate block like in the example above, I tried this :

`- (RaginiDBQuery *(^)(BOOL (^)(id object))where;`

But this gives me errors, so the question is this:

**How can I declare a block, that takes a block?**

## EDIT:

for anyone looking for the answer check below, but here is tl;dr

`- (RaginiDBQuery *(^)(BOOL(^filterBlock)(id object)))where;`

Comment: I think you just need more parenthesis: does `- (NSObject *(^)(BOOL(^)(id))) where` work for you? Would be called via `self.where(^BOOL(id obj) {return false;});` for example

Comment: In fact i think your whole mistake was just a missing closing bracket!?

Comment: Yes Indeed it was! Sometimes I make silly mistakes.

Comment: I added that as an answer as well for eventual future readers.

Comment: @luk2302, However I still have one question, If I want to save the block I get, is there anyway I can't name or retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're doing a bad thing. You should treat your difficulty as evidence that it's a misguided goal. Objective-C isn't C# or Java or even Swift. It's Objective-C. If you want to use dot notation to call functions on iOS, use Swift. Don't try to hammer Objective-C into some other language's mold.

Second, use `typedef`s.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef BOOL (^MyObject_wherePredicate)(id object);
typedef NSEnumerator *(^MyObject_whereReturn)(MyObject_wherePredicate);

@interface MyObject: NSObject

- (MyObject_whereReturn)where;

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (MyObject_whereReturn)where {
    return ^(MyObject_wherePredicate predicate) {
        NSArray *array = @[ @"hello", @"world", @"this", @"is", @"a", @"test" ];
        NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            return predicate(evaluatedObject);
        }];
        return [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p].objectEnumerator;
    };
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyObject *it = [[MyObject alloc] init];
        NSEnumerator *e = it.where(^(id object){
            NSString *string = object;
            return [string containsString:@"s"];
        });
        for (NSString *item in e) {
            NSLog(@"%@", item);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2015-05-31 12:34:31.191 commandline[1881:82976] this
2015-05-31 12:34:31.192 commandline[1881:82976] is
2015-05-31 12:34:31.192 commandline[1881:82976] test
```

Comment: Hey Rob, Thanks for the help! I know I'm doing something that I am technically not supposed to do, however, in my opinion, for my specific goal, it is the better way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The only mistake was basically a missing closing bracket. The correct method should be written as:

```
- (RaginiDBQuery *(^)(BOOL(^)(id))) where;
```

which later can be called via

```
self.where(^BOOL(id obj) {return [obj intValue] % 2 == 1;});
```

For readability sake it is however very much recommended to use typedefs as rob suggested because otherwise it gets very hard to understand what to pass in and what gets returned from your functions.

Comment: However I still have one question, If I want to save the block I get, is there anyway I can't name or retrieve it?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for - what do you want save or retrieve or rename?!

Comment: for example in this simple method `- (void)doSomething:(void (^) (BOOL success))connectionBlock` I get the block using its name, and then I can call it later using `connectionBlock()`, is there anyway I can get the block in the method you posted?

Comment: figured this out, should be used like this: `- (RaginiDBQuery *(^)(BOOL(^filterBlock)(id object)))where`

Comment: Okay, now i know what you were trying to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring a block first?

```
BOOL (^myPredicate)(id) = ^BOOL(a)
{
    return [a intValue]%2 == 1;
}
```

then declare the method you want like this

```
- (RaginiDBQuery *(^)(myPredicate predicate))where;
```